# jQuery plugin (prettyPhoto) not functioning after upload to remote server

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, prettyphoto

I would be incredibly grateful if anyone could help me understand why the [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) plugin isn't loading after uploading my site to the server.  It works fine on my local site, but not on the remote server.  The site is [here](http://www.timbentley.info/photography.html); as you can see I'm a bit of a novice, but I have tortuously checked all links and searched the web for a solution until my brain aches.

It seems that the prettyPhoto.css isn't loading properly, but why not? :-(

Thank you all and have a great Monday!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use prertyPhoto before, but I have encountered the same problem because of access privileges applied to directory in which JS/CSS files reside.

Try changing permissions of those directories recursively to `655` (I think, you need execute privilege)...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I tried changing permissions, but still not working...

Comment: Thy looking into Firebug. What does it say?

Comment: Aha - great idea - first problem was CSS folder was in uppercase, not lowercase *sighs*.  Still not working 100%, but think I can fix it now!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I know its old but someone may looking for the answers like I did :)
While uploading (using total commander for example) you have used "change file names to lowercase" option but this plugin refers to preaty**P**hoto in many cases. Upload it one more time without this option and it will work just fine :)